# Missing/wrong headers iOS 11.3 SDK

Tags: ios, xcode, delphi, c++builder

I am using C++ Builder 10.2.3 to create an app for iOS 64 bit devices. I have XCode 9.3 on my Mac (which is running High Sierra 10.13.4) and PAServer 19.0 from the CB 10.2.3 update.

I am having compile errors when building for iOS 11.3. For example, stdarg.h file not found, stddefs.h file not found. I believe there is a problem with the SDK on the Mac, or the PC, or both.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled Xcode 9.3 on the Mac.

I have deleted the iOS 11.3 SDK in SDK Manager and from the local drive, and added it back into the SDK Manager. I have updated the local file cache.

I noticed that the Remote include path shown in SDK Manager for iPhoneOS 11.3 (64 bit) shows $(SDKROOT)/../../../../../Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/9.0.0

This path does not exist on the Mac or on the PC cache. On PC cache, I find at C:\Users\\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\SDKs\iPhoneOS11.3.sdk\usr\lib with no clang subdirectory.

On the Mac, I find ../Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/9.1.0

Clearly something is missing or wrong. After many hours of searching, I have not resolved the problem and my project is at a standstill. Is anyone building apps iOS 11.3 with CB 10.2.3 and XCode 9.3? It seems like anyone using CB 10.2.3 might have this, and perhaps Delphi too if the SDK caching works the same.

Comment: $(SDKROOT)/../../../../../Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/9.0.0 look strange !

Comment: The answer to "Is anyone building apps iOS 11.3 with CB 10.2.3 and XCode 9.3?" is no, since linking against iOS 11.3 is broken in 10.2.3: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-20303. The solution is to downgrade to Xcode 9.2 and import the iOS 11.2 SDK

Comment: Thanks Dave. I've had partial success with compiling with the iOS 11.2 SDK, but I still have compile errors. I think I have either a path problem or the bccios64 compiler can't compile <cmath>