# LLVM header error: no member named 'xxxxxx' in the global namespace (iOS, C++Builder)

Tags: ios, firemonkey, c++builder, llvm-clang

**Environment description:** I'm using RAD Studio 10.2.3 Tokyo with all hotfixes installed, XCode 9.4.1, macOS High Sierra 10.13.6, iOS SDK 11.4, PAServer 10.3.1.10.

**Problem:** When I try to compile a blank application for iOS 32-bit, it is successful, and the application runs on my device.  But, if I include `<cmath>`, then during compilation I get these errors:

```
[bcciosarm Error] cmath(313): no member named 'signbit' in the global namespace
[bcciosarm Error] cmath(314): no member named 'fpclassify' in the global namespace
[bcciosarm Error] cmath(315): no member named 'isfinite' in the global namespace
[bcciosarm Error] cmath(316): no member named 'isinf' in the global namespace
[bcciosarm Error] cmath(317): no member named 'isnan' in the global namespace
[bcciosarm Error] cmath(318): no member named 'isnormal' in the global namespace
[bcciosarm Error] cmath(319): no member named 'isgreater' in the global namespace 
[bcciosarm Error] cmath(320): no member named 'isgreaterequal' in the global namespace
[bcciosarm Error] cmath(321): no member named 'isless' in the global namespace
[bcciosarm Error] cmath(322): no member named 'islessequal' in the global namespace
[bcciosarm Error] cmath(323): no member named 'islessgreater' in the global namespace
[bcciosarm Error] cmath(324): no member named 'isunordered' in the global namespace
[bcciosarm Error] cmath(325): no member named 'isunordered' in the global namespace
```

I've searching something about and I found this:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/87814

Which is the same error and it's due to **"if you combine isysroot & isystem"**

In the same way, I found a related topic in SO:

[Missing/wrong headers iOS 11.3 SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49798730/)

I would like to know, how can I fix this problem? A suggested answer is not to use **isysroot & isystem** together, but the command options are automatically generated by the IDE during compilation. So, if you have a fix or workaround to solve this, please let me know.

**Minimal and verifiable code:** Just create a blank application in C++Builder and include the `<cmath>` header in your `mainform.cpp`.

Comment: If the IDE is not supported to use `isysroot` and `isystem` together when compiling for iOS, then you should [file a bug report with Embarcadero](http://quality.embaradero.com).

Comment: Thanks @RemyLebeau but it is not a direct problem of IDE, because it problem is related to XCode.

Comment: yes, but the IDE is invocing XCode to make the build for iOS

Comment: Thanks again @RemyLebeau, the new problem reported is 
available at https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-21019